# API to build GoogleStreet-like photo maps

Tags: google-maps

Do you know if Google offers a public API to display pictures in a map as they do with Panoranio?

Just to be clear, I don't want to use Google Street, or publish my pictures anywhere in the Internet, but just have blue dots as you can see in this map if you drag and drop the orange little guy.

Answer (score 3):

"I don't want to use Google Street, or publish my pictures anywhere in the Internet"

But Google API's are public and on the internet - web access is required.

PanoMapTypeControl is the MapType

v3 does not have this (now using Streetview Pano)
as here
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/keir.clarke/web/street.htm

V2 does have **panoramio** but Internet Access is required for API key and javascript
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/panoramio/pano_layer.html
images you have will be required to be uploaded and geotagged

blue dots are part of Google Maps (not API) Streetview layer.

Comment: thanks; "Google API's are public ... " sure, I know, but I can use their API without publishing anything online! The v3 example is interesting, but not what I was looking for; I will take a look at the V2 example, I guess what I actually what to do is customize the GM Streeview layer with my geotags/pictures

Comment: @Kevin might want to double-check the terms of use before going ahead with a project that uses the GMaps APIs in a non-publicly-available context

Comment: @JasonBirch I will do for sure; maybe it'll scare me out and I'll switch to OpenStreet map or equivalent ;)